# how to use i2c driver in kernel space

Tags: linux, kernel, i2c

I have wrote a character driver to control my embedded hardware with my application, In my driver there is a feature to send a command to an I2C device which is connected to my embedded device.

in command line I am able to send the following code to my device:

```
i2cset  -y 0 0x2c 0x00 0x05
```

I want to do same thing in kernel space within my driver, but I did not find a sample, all I got was in userspace, how can I do that in kernel space?

edit:

I know that with "[i2c_master_send](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.14/driver-api/i2c.html#c.i2c_master_send)" or "[i2c_smbus_read_byte](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.14/driver-api/i2c.html#c.i2c_smbus_read_byte)" function I can send data to i2c devices, bu this function gets a structure called "[i2c_client](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.14/driver-api/i2c.html#c.i2c_client)", I don't know how should I suppose to fill this structure to send data. It might be really silly but I could not figure it out how can I fill this structure.

Comment: You need to understand how to write device drivers for Linux in general, and then understand the specifics of the I2C subsystem in the Linux kernel, described in https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/i2c/writing-clients.html

Comment: Can you share details of the hardware? Is it custom or mass production? Any datasheet links? It's quite possible that driver is already there, if it's mass production one.

Comment: LucaCeresoli and 0andriy thank you for your response, I already read the article you mentioned, but I did not understand how can I fill i2c_client and there is no describing in how to do so. my device is on i2c0 and I can put data directly on that. so there is no need to use any driver I suppose... I saw some drivers for i2c devices, in those drivers the functions I mentioned earlier used to send data to i2c bus, but no  describing to how fill client structure either...

Comment: Actually using the in-kernel driver is a right thing to do.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have reached my goal with following code in my driver:

****Please read my edit before using this code*****

```
#define VOL1_CHIP_ADDRESS 0x2c
#define VOL1_DATA_ADDRESS 0

struct i2c_client *clientstr;
struct file * fp;

...

mm_segment_t oldfs;

oldfs = get_fs();
set_fs(KERNEL_DS);
fp = filp_open("/dev/i2c-0",O_RDWR,0);
clientstr = (struct i2c_client *)fp->private_data;
clientstr->addr=VOL1_CHIP_ADDRESS;
i2c_smbus_write_byte_data(clientstr,VOL1_DATA_ADDRESS,0x05);
filp_close(fp,NULL);
set_fs(oldfs);
```

**EDIT:**

So I did what I wanted in kernel, opening a file in kernel space regardless of any suggestions not to do so.

But I needed to open a file in kernel module...

So why every body said don't open user space files in kernel?
In these two articles there are some reasons to not using files in kernel , [this link](http://lkml.iu.edu/hypermail/linux/kernel/0005.3/0061.html) and [this link](https://www.linuxjournal.com/article/8110).

there are some reasons like:
1- kernel module may lose CPU at any time and the file which is opened by kernel may close.

2- I am not sure really about this, But they said files needs to have a process to stay opened but kernel module itself is not a process(maybe I am wrong!).

3- If any error happens while working with files(open/close/read/write), kernel module can not handle it and causes kernel panic...

I have experienced a lot of kernel panics only while opening and closing the file I wanted to work with. These are some of reasons why you should not use files in kernel modules, So as every body said before "If you need to use files in kernel module you probably did something wrong in your code!"

Comment: @0andriy you said it was wrong... thanks for your help and time. now I know exactly why it is a wrong approach.

Comment: You are keeping secrecy about hardware, how can we help here except pointing out to the wrong approach? I already told you that you need to use in-kernel driver for your specific hardware. Above code is not what's called the I²C client driver, it's... see the first comment.

Comment: Oh, boy, I may see sarcasm where none actually were being applied... Sorry.